# Chromecast displays web page without any device connected to it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromecast

I was wondering if somebody could tell me if the chromecast allows to display a webpage through chrome tab mirroring with the computer shutdown.

I would like just to tell the chromecast to display a specific webpage and then shutdown my devices and let the screen display that page and refreshing it every X min.

Do you know if it's possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is mirroring, no, you won't be able to do that since when you shutdown your computer, everything is gone, and there is nothing to mirror (remember, you are not telling it to show the content of a page, you are telling it to "mirror" your screen and chromecast doesn't have any clue what that content is). You should write a sender and receive app to accomplish that. Also think about user experience: how does user stop that process?